# Crash when replacing existing image

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been Working on a c# program that takes a screenshot every second, but it always crashes after the second screenshot.

[image: pic of the error]

I guess it's maybe because it fails to save the image as the name was already taken by the previous screenshot.

it crashes at this line exactly :

```
screenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I want it to overwrite the image every time without any crashes.

Comment: could we get some code where it is failing at?

Comment: `I guess it's maybe because fails to save it as the name is already taken by the previous screenshot` It's easy to find out: delete the file after taking the first screenshot, then see if the second one still crashes

Comment: @KevinGosse it works perfectly when there's no file with the same name, but can't it just overwrite the image without another function to delete it ?

Comment: 'screenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", format: ImageFormat.Png);' @Darnold in this line.

Comment: In regards to your comment "I'm not allowed to embed images in my posts yet :(", a simple and preferable solution to that is to provide that information as text - **not** an image - in the first place.  Being able to see what the error dialog _looks like_ really doesn't add any value, whereas it's helpful for respondents to be able to copy-and-paste your error code, your error message, and parts of your stack trace.  It also means that the critical information in your post can be consumed by search engines and screen readers, to which those details are currently "invisible".

Comment: @KevinGosse and the program wouldn't delete the image as it's still being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code for replacing already created file, but be sure that you have already released previous file handle. If you use using like the code below, the operation for disposing thus releasing file handle is done automatically

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create,  
   FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
{
    image.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Png) //example format for saving file
}
```

Comment: As a previously existing file should be replaced/overwritten, the FileStream constructor can be substituted by a simple and short `File.Create(filePath)`

Comment: Also, I think `FileMode.Create` is better than `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`. According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.7.2), `OpenOrCreate` won't truncate the file (so if the second screenshot is smaller than the first one, there will be garbage at the end of the file)

Comment: @KevinGosse, true. +1 (i didn't even notice the answer used OpenOrCreate)